# Index/Match Multiple Criteria, Perform Calculation for Each Match

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have two columns in a table that are known as S and D, where S is a date, and D is a duration.
E.g.:

```
'S' Column
January
February
March
April

'D' Column
60
30
45
30
```

On a separate sheet, imagine that Row 1 contains a sequence of dates (variable, depends on user menu selection).

Row 2 requires the following calculation:

```
[(x - s1)/d1 + (x-s2)/d2 + ... + (x-sn)/dn] / n
```

...where "x" is any date along Row 1.

The calculation would only be done when multiple criteria are matched.

My initial attempt involved creating a separate table, but I think this can be done in a one-cell formula in Row 2. I don't think a sum(index(match)) type would work here considering d1, d2, ..., dn are denominators with different values.

Here is an example attempt:

```
=SUM((SelectedDate-INDEX(Table[StartDates],MATCH(Criteria1&Criteria2,Range1&Range2,0))/INDEX(Table[Durations],MATCH(Criteria1&Criteria2,Range1&Range2,0))))
```

It may be important to note that I am able to do this in a two-step fashion. First,  I create a table that does the calculation on each row. Then, I reference the table. It would be nice if I can eliminate the need of a "calculation table" in favour of an array-type formula.

Comment: "The calculation would only be done when multiple criteria are matched." Do we need to know those criteria? Or do you just want a solution to the problem as stated, which you will then incorporate into e.g. a further IF statement?
Also, your example dates are all simply months (i.e. no days/years) - how is this resolved with regards to the subtraction you outline?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. To your first question, yes. To the second question, no, they are specific dates. I have edited with an example attempt of translating the formula into syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I know a lot of people rave about Structured References, but I personally can't abide them, particularly when it comes to intricate formula-work, so unfortunately I'll have to pass. Regards.

Comment: I am flexible to other options (non-VBA).

Comment: I might have a go if you first convert your Table to a normal range (Design/Convert to Range) and post an updated version of your outline formula.

Comment: It would be something like this:
=SUM((SelectedDate-INDEX(A1:A300,MATCH(Criteria1&Criteria2,Range1&Range2,0))/INDEX(B1:B300,MATCH(Criteria1&Criteria2,Range1&Range2,0))))

Comment: Thanks. And the INDEXing is actually being done on a separate sheet to that containing the SelectedDates? And when you say Criteria1, etc. that's actually a GROUP of criteria? So that you'll be returning more than one element from A1:A300 and B1:B300 to be passed to the SUM?

Comment: Correct. The source data is a "master data" type of sheet, and the SelectedDates is a "report" type of sheet, where a date is selected and updates a series of weeks. Under each week in that series, the calculation is being performed. Going to update original post with additional information.

Comment: Sorry - updated my comment after you replied. Can you confirm the other part?

Comment: It is indeed a group of criteria, but they're just identifiers. In this case, I have A, B, C, and some subgroups, like A1, A2, A3. These identifiers are in other columns, and aren't an issue for me to incorporate into syntax.

Comment: Are the Criteria variables, i.e. each of the SelectedDates has its own set of Criteria? Or is the part: INDEX(A1:A300,MATCH(Criteria1&Criteria2,Range1&Range2,0))/IND‌EX(B1:B300,MATCH(Criteria1&Criteria2,Range1&Range2,0)) constant and independent of the SelectedDate in question?

Comment: Just like how a user can select a date, they can select whether they want to view group A or group B data.

Comment: That didn't answer my question.

Comment: Somehow the other piece of my answer didn't go through. They are independent of the SelectedDate, and the cell references are constant. They just vary in what the criteria is. If my Criteria is in Column C, and the criteria in the match() formula matches against a group of 10 rows in column A, then the calculation I am trying to achieve would work on those 10 rows.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand. So you're saying that I don't actually need to worry about accounting for these Criteria in my solution? That if I just give you a generic formula with Criteria1, Criteria2, etc. in return, that will be sufficient?

Comment: Correct, that would be great. The current solution I have is two step. If your solution can be 1-step, I would be very interested. What I mean by two-step is: in the first "master data" sheet, for every row of data, I perform the calculation in say, column D. The calculation is a simple subtract then divide. Then in "report sheet", I use index/match to retrieve the values based on the criteria.

Comment: Sorry, but now I'm confused by your syntax. Your suggested formula is matching the Criteria against the Ranges: shouldn't that be the other way around? And I'm afraid it's still not clear what form these "generic" criteria take. If I assume for the sake of argument that Criteria1 is the array {"Red","Yellow","Green"}, is that to say that each of the 300 entries from the range is to be tested against whether it is equal to ANY of these values? Sorry - I think this may beyond discussing theoretically, and I apologise for wasting your time, but without seeing a workbook I'm not sure I can help.

Comment: Not wasting time at all. You're partially correct in your example, that each of the 300 entries would be tested to see if Red is true (depending on user choice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a guess before most of the comments and suggest the following mainly in case it provides ay ideas or is of help in specifying the requirement more closely. This is "two-step" because the average formula is separate from that for each column, so I appreciate may well be not what is required.

Assuming S and D are labelled data in Sheet2 ColumnsA:B.
Assuming Row1 data rows are labelled in ColumnA.
Assuming dates are not strings (eg January is actually Jan 1) and the differences are in days and always positive, etc.

```
=(B$1-CHOOSE(COLUMN(),Sheet2!$A1,Sheet2!$A2,Sheet2!$A3,Sheet2!$A4))/CHOOSE(COLUMN(),Sheet2!$B1,Sheet2!$B2,Sheet2!$B3,Sheet2!$B4)
```

in Row2 to suit and if four data columns, in F2 and copied down to suit :

```
=AVERAGE(B2:E2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about the Choose() function, but this would work only for up to 254 rows of data, correct?

Comment: Yeah, but there is a one-to-many relationship with the dates.

Comment: There are multiple data points for each date. I could have multiple January 1sts, multiple January 2nd, etc.